# WebService non-standard Authorization Type

Tags: web-services, authorization, asmx

I have a service provider that requires a non-standard Authorization Type for their web service.

Instead of Basic, Digest, NTLM, etc., they require "Basic API Access.".

I have tried the code below and used Fiddler to check the web service request.

It does not seem that any custom strings can be used

```
    Binding avail = new Binding();
    avail.Url = "https://amer.webservicesxx.com/Availability";

    NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential("abc", "def");
    Uri uri = new Uri(avail.Url);

    CredentialCache cred = new CredentialCache();
    cred.Add(uri, "Basic API Access", netCredential);
    avail.Credentials = cred;

    SearchRsp response = avail.service(request);
```

> POST https://amer.webservicesxx.com/Availability HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client
>   Protocol 4.0.30319.1)
>  VsDebuggerCausalityData:
>   uIDPo+CJPwpspBxKp939c...
>  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   SOAPAction: ""
>  Host: america.webservicesxx.com
>  Content-Length:
>   658
>  Expect: 100-continue
>
> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ?soap:Envelope
>   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/20 01/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  ...
>     ?/soap:Envelope>

It is missing the ...

**Authorization: Basic API Access/dUFQSS04NDA0NTk2MDk6WiFyYzBuZDg0...**

...line in the header.

If I just use `"Basic"` it adds the Authorization line properly, but is rejected by the service provider.

Is this the correct syntax to add an `Authorization:` header to the Soap transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to replace data in the web request.

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
     WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic API Access dUFQSS04NDA0NT...");

     return request; 
 }
```

inside the web service reference class.